# Creating an LDAP Server With PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I'm looking to create a web based application in PHP that receives LDAP requests and sends LDAP responses back, but doesn't actually use an LDAP server. Specifically I'd like to make the contacts table in a MySQL database available to Thunderbird as an LDAP address book.

Two Questions:

1. Is there an existing library for implementing an LDAP server with PHP? (The PHP_LDAP package is for creating an LDAP client, where the PHP application connects to an existing LDAP server.)
2. How does LDAP data actually get from the client into my script? Does LDAP travel over HTTP? Where the request would show up in:

   ```
   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
   ```

or similar? Can Apache handle LDAP requests and pass them into my script or is it a completely different protocol that requires a different "listener" application to handle?

Comment: OpenLDAP can be configured to [use an SQL database as a backend](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html) directly. It isn't as fully-featured as the native OpenLDAP BDB, but might meet your needs without a line of PHP. (Which wouldn't be my first choice of implementation language for a new LDAP server, not by a long shot. :)

Comment: I had tried getting back-sql working a while back but eventually gave up because I couldn't even get it to compile properly. Basically we have a CRM based on PHP/MySQL, and somehow we need to make the contacts available to Thunderbird as an address book. I suppose we could use a real LDAP server and have our CRM (As a client) update the LDAP database, but that seems really inefficient. I wonder if it might be easier to create a JSON address book plug-in for Thunderbird, and skip LDAP entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LDAP protocol is not natively handled by Apache, and I've not seen any Apache modules that handle that protocol. I don't believe you'll be able to do it using PHP through Apache. You might be able to implement a pure PHP server (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) and then implement the LDAP protocol packet parser in PHP as well. I don't believe there is a native ASN1 parser for PHP, but you might be able to find one in C and somehow integrate it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It sounds like it would be much more work than it's worth to implement an LDAP server in PHP. I'm going to look into the possibility of modifying Thunderbird to get address data via JSON or XML requests over http(s).

Comment: Ah: if that's what you're looking for maybe something like gContactsSync (see http://gcontactsync.mozdev.org/) will give you a base to start from.

Comment: Ah: took me forever to find it, but you may want to look at Penrose (see http://penrose.redhat.com/display/PENROSE/Home), which is in java but (in theory) lets you back ldap with any storage structure (so you write an adapter to your address book backend and Penrose exposes it via LDAP),

Comment: Interesting... I'll look into those and see if they'll work. Wonder what the learning curve is like for Penrose?

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to create a pure PHP LDAP server with this library (I wrote it initially for LDAP client purposes):

https://github.com/FreeDSx/LDAP

It works on the basis of a request handler (just an interface) for client requests. Basically you extend a class that will handle client requests and send a response back (in the case of a search anyway). A basic example:

1. Create a request handler extending the generic request handler in  the library:

```php
namespace Foo;

use FreeDSx\Ldap\Server\RequestHandler\GenericRequestHandler;

class LdapRequestHandler extends GenericRequestHandler
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $users = [
        'user' => '12345',
    ];

    /**
     * Validates the username/password of a simple bind request
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return bool
     */
    public function bind(string $username, string $password): bool
    {
        return isset($this->users[$username]) && $this->users[$username] === $password;
    }

    /**
     * Override the search request. This must send back an entries object.
     *
     * @param RequestContext $context
     * @param SearchRequest $search
     * @return Entries
     */
    public function search(RequestContext $context, SearchRequest $search): Entries
    {
        // Do your logic here with the search request, return entries...
        return new Entries(
            Entry::create('cn=Foo,dc=FreeDSx,dc=local', [
                'cn' => 'Foo',
                'sn' => 'Bar',
                'givenName' => 'Foo',
            ]),
            Entry::create('cn=Chad,dc=FreeDSx,dc=local', [
                'cn' => 'Chad',
                'sn' => 'Sikorra',
                'givenName' => 'Chad',
            ])
        );
    }
}
```

2. Using the request handler, create a LDAP server process that listens on port 389 for clients:

```php
use FreeDSx\Ldap\LdapServer;
use Foo\LdapRequestHandler;

$server = new LdapServer([ 'request_handler' => LdapRequestHandler::class ]);
$server->run();
```

There are more docs on the server component of the library here:

https://github.com/FreeDSx/LDAP/tree/master/docs/Server

A few caveats to this:

- Currently no paging / vlv support for the server
- Currently no way to return controls from the request handler back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I worked with a really smart dev who said he implemented a working LDAP client / server in PHP. He published it under the MIT license here: https://code.google.com/p/ldap-php/.

I have no idea what the state of this is though.